# Is it possible to use brace initialization of a dynamic array using std::make_unique?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Typically, we can create an array using brace initialization of dynamic allocation by

```
int* arr = new int[5]{1,1,2,4,5};
```

But would this be possible using smart pointers, specifically using std::make_unique? I've tried the following:

```
unique_ptr<int[]> arr(5) {1,1,2,4,5};
unique_ptr<int[]> arr = make_unique<int[]>(5){1,1,2,4,5};
unique_ptr<int[]> arr = make_unique<int[]>({1,1,2,4,5});
```

But no avail, and I am getting to a point where I think this might not even be possible using smart pointers. Any suggestions on how to go about using **brace initialization** for smart pointers would be appreciated.

Yes, I am aware of `std::vector` but was hoping if there was a alternative way.

Answer (score 7):

> Would this be possible using smart pointers, specifically using `std::make_unique`?

No, you can not do with the [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) as it has special implementation for the arrays, and it is restricted only for unknown bound.

From *cppreference.com*, for the **unknown bound**, `std::make_unique` has only the overload<sup>2</sup>

> ```
> (only for array types with unknown bound)
> template< class T >
> unique_ptr<T> make_unique( std::size_t size ); (2) (Since C++14)
> ```
>
> 2. Constructs an array of the given dynamic size. The array elements are **[value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)**. This overload participates in overload resolution only if `T` is an array of unknown bound.

This means, in your case it creates the dynamic array of the given size and the integers will be initialized to `0`, and can not pass the initialization values.

---

> Any suggestions on how to go about using brace initialization for smart pointers would be appreciated.

You can do without the `std::make_unique`, something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr{ new int[]{1, 1, 2, 4, 5} };
```

or write your own `make_unique` which will create a dynamic array of the type of the elements you passed and initialized with the values you passed.

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>  // std::common_type

template<typename... Args>
auto make_unique_init(Args&&... args)
{
    using Type = std::common_type_t<Args...>;
    return std::unique_ptr<Type[]>(new Type[sizeof...(args)]{ std::forward<Args>(args)... });
}
```

Now you can write:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr2 = make_unique_and_init(1, 1, 2, 4, 5);
```

Here is an [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) [working example code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8bfboq3sh).