# Is it possible to initialize elements of a unique_ptr array?

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator, unique-ptr

I was using heap memory as part of a small example, and I ended up writing this:

```
    double* p = new double[4] { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
...
    delete[] p;
```

Later, I wanted to upgrade this to a `std::unique_ptr`:

```
    std::unique_ptr<double[]> arrp(new double[4] { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 });
...
```

(no need for `delete[]`).

Of course, it is always better to use `std::make_unique` rather than new, but **how can initialize an array of elements with `std::make_unique`?**

Comment: I'm more curious why you're not using `std::vector`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I wanted to show an example of a class referring to memory in the heap without other straneous implications. (Quoting a comment I saw in the linked answer, "std::vector<T> is not basically std::unique_ptr<T[]>; the requirements on the type (be copyable/movable, default constructible, etc.) are not the same.")  (The example/test code is here: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/test/array_ref.cpp?ref_type=heads#L101-129)

Comment: It's a missed opportunity in the language. _init-lists_ and `make_unique` suffer - you'll have to roll your own to get around  this defect.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, yes, probably, it is more than a library implementation limitation, a factory function that that takes a `std::initializer_list` (if that is what you mean) will need to copy the elements (in the the newly allocated memory instead of creating them in place).

Comment: @alfC _All_ library functions where an `initializer_list` is involved will have to copy the values. I'm not a big fan. Good for nice initialization of fixtures. Crap for everything else.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, *that* is a missed opportunity.

Comment: I got so annoyed that I made my own yesterday :-) Hence my tone ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Your own `initializer_list`? How? I worked my tail off to make nested initializer-list to initialize rectangular arrays (and it still is quite inefficient)

Comment: @alfC I'm removing the link now so noone starts using it in its current shape. I may do something with that idea when I've calmed down :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo, fair; I would like to try your super-dupper init list in the future, even if it just allows moving elements.

Comment: @alfC The super-duper `initialize` not only moves, it forwards when possible. :-) Oh well, I'm too close to packing it up to go ranting about "shit I find ridiculous" so I'll probably just live with it.

Comment: [Is it possible to use brace initialization of a dynamic array using std::make_unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69581072/is-it-possible-to-use-brace-initialization-of-a-dynamic-array-using-stdmake-un) and [Why is std::make_unique not implemented using list initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141594/why-is-stdmake-unique-not-implemented-using-list-initialization)

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, here is a bad, no-good, inefficient implementation that I do not necessarily want to use.

At best it would clarify what I want in the question.

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

namespace xtd {
    template<class T, class T2>
    auto make_unique(std::initializer_list<T2> il) {
        if constexpr(std::is_array_v<T>) {
            std::unique_ptr<T> ret(new std::remove_extent_t<T>[il.size()]);
            std::copy(il.begin(), il.end(), ret.get());  // not std::uninitialized_copy
            return ret;
        } else {
            return std::make_unique<T>(il);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<double[]> p(new double[4] { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 });

    auto q = xtd::make_unique<double[]>({0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0});
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/d11h8WhEo

Comment: Note that `xstd::make_unique<T[]>(il)` behaves improperly if `T` has a nontrivial destructor.

Comment: @RaymondChen, do you mean “improperly” because it will destruct what is in the init list? Which doesn't happen in the original pure-new version?

Comment: The `new std::remove_extent_t<T>[il.size()]` allocates and constructs `il.size()` objects. Then the `uninitialized_copy` overwrites them without destructing them first. If the destructor is nontrivial, those destructors may have had to do something important. `std::uninitialized_copy` is for copying to uninitialized data, but if `T` has a nontrival constructor, then the memory has been initialized.

Comment: @RaymondChen, sure, then using std::copy was more correct. For some reason I though unique_ptr<T[]> wasn't initialized, but of course not after doing `new T[n]`.

Comment: @RaymondChen, in addition, I think the solution I posted is not good because it adds the requirement to be default constructible. I guess only a version with variadic arguments can do the trick.